# getting subprocess result in variable

Tags: python, subprocess

I am executing python script using `subprocess.call()` in pytho script. The script which gets executed using `subproecss` is a `server` process which send result back to calling client.

```
result = subprocess.call('python -m module/coref_resolution/src/coref/corenlp &', shell = True)
```

Is there any way to receive result from corenlp.py into `result` variable?

Comment: you should import the module instead and call (in a separate process using multiprocessing if you'd like) the necessary functions to get the result. Why do you use `&` at end here?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: to put it as deamon process in  background. I am running couple of processes in sequence. Otherwise it was getting stopped being daemon process, listening on port 8080

Comment: you don't need the shell job control inside a Python script. Use subprocess.Popen instead. Drop `shell=True`, use a list to pass the command

Answer (score 1):

```
import shlex
cmd = shlex.split('your command')
output = subprocess.Popen( cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: you could write it as `output = subprocess.check_output(['command', 'arg1', 'arg2'])`